# One of Many Entity Relation

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4

On Symfony 4, I have an Entity (Address) which can be associated with **ONE** Of Many entities: e.g. Accounts, Contacts, Employees ..etc.

I essentially want to have "entity_type" and "entity_id" columns in Address but I am unsure if this is the best way to proceed since I would still like to be able to make use of Forms ...etc.

Comment: Are you using Doctrine 2?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could do like that. But, that will limit the capabilities of one address being shared with multiplie entities such as `contacts`, `employees` and so on (unless duplicating the record). However, if one address record never shares with multiple entities you can go ahead and do that.

How about having third table which holds the mapping between `address` and `employees`, `contacts` and so on? Let's say a new table called `entity_address`, the structure would look like this,

- id
- entity_id
- entity_name
- address_id (foreign key to id column of address table)

I personally prefer this approach, instead of having the `address` table to have `entity_id` and `entity_name` due to the reason I mentioned in the first paragraph.

Having said that, someone else, might have a different approach.

Anyway, happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can think your relation to the other side.

An account can have many addresses. A contact can have many addresses. An employee can have many addresses.

This is a Many-To-Many Unidirectionnal relation.

You can build the relation in the target entity, rather than in the address one.

```
class Accounts
{
    // ...

    /*
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Address")
     * @ORM\JoinTable
     * (
     *     name="accounts_addresses",
     *     joinColumns=
     *     {
     *         @ORM\JoinColumn(name="account_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *     },
     *     inverseJoinColumns=
     *     {
     *         @ORM\JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)
     *     }
     * )
     */
    private $addresses;

    // ...
}

// And so on for the others entities
```

This will build an relationship table in your database with a unique constraint on the address_id foreign key.

For more informations, take a look at [this](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table)

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying - each entity (account, contact, employee) can have multiple addresses.